# How to concurrently read and write to a file in Java

Tags: java, file, concurrency, io

Say I had 2 Java programs running simultaneously, one writes to a file using PrintWriter and then closes it and repeats this process, and the other program constantly reads the file as it is being written, without closing the BufferedReader until it ran to the bottom of the file. Would the BufferedReader being open stop the file from being written to?/ would this work?/ is there a better way of doing this?

Program 1 (contents of method called around once every 10 minutes):

```
public void write(String text){
    PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    wr.println(text);
    wr.close();
}
```

Program 2

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(followerFile));
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //do something
}

br.close();
```

Comment: Can you not try and see if it works?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: You need to have something which support sending messages between two JVMs. This is usually done over TCP, UDP but you can use files, but not as simply as this. You could use a named pipe to make this code work.

Comment: You can do it using `Socket Programming`! Give it a try.

Comment: If all you want to do is read and write from a file at the same time (and essentially in the same program) then use [`RandomAccessFile`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv6enr6JHQAhVCuI8KHSx2A9gQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fio%2FRandomAccessFile.html&usg=AFQjCNGm_o3hbnFpe-hp3RzDG30qJKQlnw).